# Magento 2 Service/HttpExceptionStrategyFactory.php error

Tags: magento2.3

Could you please help me?

I have this error with my magento2 installation:

> vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/HttpExceptionStrategyFactory.php
>   on line 29

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add your `composer.json`....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure file `vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/ExceptionStrategy.php` is in place, if not you may need to re-upload the source files or delete the vendor directory content and run `composer install` depending on how you install Magento.